# Irregular growth on roses

Tags: roses

My roses have been experiencing some crazy irregular growth, this appeared at the beginning of spring has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like "rose rosette disease", which is a virus infection transmitted by insects.

There is no known cure, but it only spreads slowly from the infected part of the plant, so cutting out the entire stems that are affected (not just the unwanted growths) may control it - unless it gets re-infected by more insects, of course.

See https://www.finegardening.com/article/rose-rosette-disease-what-to-do-when-you-get-it, for example.